# how to set datetime from java to sql with Date today = new Date();

Tags: java, sql-server

I set Date today = new Date(); this value to input on html that show me this
Sat May 18 22:42:32 ICT 2019

but in sql server i get the value is 2019-05-18 00:00:00 with smalldatetime type. How can I get the value of the day and hour?

code in Java class

```
              Date today = new Date();
              Datenow dn = new Datenow();
              dn.setToday(today);
              dateFacade.create(dn);
```

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Date`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `LocalDateTime` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: What is `Datenow`?

Answer (score 2):

While storing data are you using `java.sql.Date` because if it is the case then time value will be truncated. You have to use `java.sql.Timestamp` instead.

[Refer Java Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html)

Comment: If you find this useful then please accept the answer.

Comment: While it works, it’s the old-fashioned answer. Since JDBC 4.2 instead of `java.sql.Timestamp` you should use either `LocalDateTime` (for a date and time of day) or `OffsetDateTime` (for a point in time).

Comment: Both `java.sql.Date` and `java.sql.Timestamp` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. `Date` is replaced by `LocalDate`. `Timestamp` is replaced by `java.time.Instant` generally, and specifically in JDBC by `java.time.OffsetDateTime`.. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

You are mixing the **wrong data types** in both your database and your Java code, trying to represent a moment yet stripping off crucial zone/offset information. But if you insist:

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject (
    … ,
    OffsetDateTime.now( ZoneOffset.UTC ).toLocalDateTime()  // Or some other `ZoneId` or `ZoneOffset` object.
) ;
```

## Types in MS SQL Server

The [`smalldatetime` type in Microsoft SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/smalldatetime-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) is a non-standard legacy type. The documentation recommends using other types nowadays. Note that future dates are limited to June 6, 2079.

This type represents simply a date and a time-of-day, resolving to whole seconds. So this types does *not* represent a moment. Without the context of a time zone or offset-from-UTC, we cannot determine a moment. A `smalldatetime` represents *potential* moments along a range of about 26-27 hours, the range of time zones around the globe. So for example, 2019-01-23 12:00:00 might mean noon in Tokyo, or noon in Kolkata, or noon in Paris, or noon in Montréal — all of these being different moments several hours apart from one another.

## Types in Java

You are using terrible date-time classes (`java.sql.Date` or `java.util.Date`) that are now legacy, supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

The `smalldatetime` equivalent type in Java is [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDateTime.html), a date with time-of-day but no time zone or offset-from-UTC.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.of( 2018 , Month.MAY , 18 , 22 , 42 , 22 ) ;
```

With JDBC 4.2 and later, we can directly exchange some of the *java.time* types with the database. I do not use Microsoft SQL Server, so I have not tried this. But you should be able to sent a `LocalDateTime` Java object to a `smalldatetime` column.

Use a  prepared statement with a `?` placeholder in your SQL code.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , ldt ) ;
```

Retrieval.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = myResultSet.getObject( … , LocalDateTime.class ) ;
```

## Current moment

> Date today = new Date();

First, be aware of the difference between `java.util.Date` and `java.sql.Date`. The first represents a moment in UTC. The second pretends to represent a date-only without time-of-day and without a zone/offset, but actually has both a time-of-day and a zone/offset as it inherits from the other `Date` in a horribly bad hack of a class design. You should not be using either `Date` class.

Apparently you are trying to represent the current moment in your `smalldatetime` column. **This makes no sense.** As discussed above, you cannot represent a moment in `smalldatetime`. So you are inappropriately mixing the wrong types.

If you insist on proceeding, you can fake it I suppose.

Let's capture the current moment.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;  // Capture the current moment in UTC.
```

JDBC 4.2 does not require support for `Instant`. So let's convert that to a `OffsetDateTime` object specifying an offset-from-UTC of zero hours-minutes-seconds for a moment in UTC itself.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = instant.atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
```

Shortcut: Capture current moment as `OffsetDateTime`.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.now( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
```

If you were properly using a column of a type akin to the SQL-standard `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`, you would pass that `OffsetDateTime`.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , odt ) ;
```

But we need to [strip off the offset-from-UTC](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html#toLocalDateTime()) info as a hack to fit your `smalldatetime` column.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = odt.toLocalDateTime() ;  // Data loss: Discarding valuable information about offset-from-UTC.
```

Send that `LocalDateTime` object to database as mentioned above.

```
myPreparedStatment.setObject( … , ldt ) ;
```

Shortcut that I do *not* recommend: Call `now` on `LocalDateTime`. In my opinion, including the method `LocalDateTime.now` in the *java.time* API was a mistake. I cannot imagine when calling that is appropriate. Doing so in this case will be confusing to the reader as we would not know if you comprehended the issues involved in trying to store a moment yet failing to include zone/offset info.

But if you insist against my advice:

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject (
    … ,
    LocalDateTime.now( ZoneOffset.UTC )  // Or some other `ZoneId` or `ZoneOffset` object.
) ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).